# pm2 crash with too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored" in python

Tags: python-2.7, pm2, django-errors, pm2-logrotate

I have created a script that can run the python django application. I run this script using `pm2`.
I do `pm2 start scripts.sh`, it works properly but after some time my application doesn't work and displays an error like this

> the runtime process for the instance running on port 37001 has unexpectedly quit**

I show the log using `pm2 logs`, it displays an error like this

> script.sh had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"

How to resolved it? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Primarily I have created a configuration file using the following command:

```
cd ~
pm2 init
sudo nano ecosystem.config.js
```

Then copy and paste the following code into the newly created `ecosystem.config.js` file (note: change your project location in `cwd` section):

```
apps: [
    {
        name: 'my-site',
        cwd: ' /home/your-name/your-project-directory',
        script: 'npm',
        args: 'start',
        env: {
              NODE_PUBLIC_APP: 'NODE_PUBLIC_APP', // for example
        },
   },
   // optionally a second project
],};
```

After that before running the app using `pm2` I did the following:

```
pm2 kill
sudo rm -rf node_modules
npm i
```

Then I run the application in watch mode, so that I can see what is going on using `pm2 log` later. To run the app in watch mode do the following:

```
pm2 start npm --name "AnyAppName" -- run start --watch
```

And finally I see the logs what causes the error by running the following command:

```
pm2 log
```

Hope this helps someone in the future like me.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue and resolved with:
pm2 kill
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
pm2 start index.js

sudo shutdown -r now